# LoggerMessage structured logging

Tags: c#, .net, ilogger

I'm using LoggerMessage [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/high-performance-logging#define-a-logger-message) in my application. I want to use structured logging like below. But I don't see a way. Is this possible in LoggerMessage ?

```
logger.LogInformation("Test {id}",id)
```

**Update:**

To make it clear, I like to achieve something similar to [ILogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#log-message-template) . Using single logger instance we can log any message with any number of placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I like to achieve something similar to ILogger. Using single logger instance we can log any message with any number of placeholders.

Then use ILogger.

LoggerMessage sacrifices usability for performance. It does this by pre-parsing the message template so you don't have to incur the cost of parsing whenever you log that message. The upshot of this is that you have to use a separate LoggerMessage instance for each message template.

> Logger extension methods must parse the message template (named format string) every time a log message is written. LoggerMessage only requires parsing a template once when the message is defined.
> -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/high-performance-logging

If you're okay with that trade-off, use LoggerMessage the way it's documented. Or, better yet, [use the LoggerMessage attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logger-message-generator) for precompiled message templates.

Otherwise, use the ILogger extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's right there in the documentation you have linked, right?

```cs
s_processingPriorityItem = LoggerMessage.Define<WorkItem>(
    LogLevel.Information,
    new EventId(1, nameof(PriorityItemProcessed)),
    "Processing priority item: {Item}");
```

In your case you would define a logger message like this:

```cs
private static Action<ILogger, string, Exception> _loggerMessage;

// ...

_loggerMessage = LoggerMessage.Define<string>(
    logLevel: LogLevel.Information,
    eventId: 1,
    formatString: "Test {id}");
```

And then use it like this:

```cs
_loggerMessage(_logger, id, null);
```

Or even better, use the `LoggerMessage` attribute like this:

```cs
[LoggerMessage(1, LogLevel.Information, "Test {id}", EventName = "TestId")]
public static partial void TestId(ILogger logger, string id);
```

Comment: s_processingPriorityItem(logger, $"Test {id}", null) , string interpolation like this works. But I couldn't make it work with structured logging like s_processingPriorityItem(logger, "Test {id}", id, null)

Comment: It works with structured properties too. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: you are just passing the id in the logger message. Each message could be different as well. _loggerMessage(_logger, "Different message {id}", id, null).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question then. If you need to log "Different message {id}" you'd need another LoggerMessage. For inspiration: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2575e22efba6d07862b951fbe50ff28659e11ee7/src/SignalR/clients/csharp/Client.Core/src/HubConnection.Log.cs

Comment: Sorry the question wasn't clear enough. I added more details now. I like to use one LoggerMessage delegate for all Information logs, but it should accept different messages and placeholders.

Comment: That's not how it is designed. If you check out the github link, you can see a good example of how to generate methods for multiple logger messages.